# Text field hidden while android keyboard open in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am facing one big problem in android phonegap application. I have 5 or 6 text filed and 2 drop down field in one single page, if i enter to type in first text filed is scrolling up and also i cant to see want i am typing in this field, in my android key board i click next button and focusing text field is not visible for me some text field only visible. i am using cordova 1.8.0 and jquery mobile1.1.1. in my android manifest file i am using the following line,

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"

but its not working fine,

Any one can know the reason, any body facing this problem.

Comment: I think this could be an issue with PhoneGap or Android. Try also setting fullscreen to false in the manifest file.

Comment: you can check this post,works nice.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29706953/4071287

Comment: you can check this post,works nice

 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29706953/4071287

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same issue.
In Android manifest file add **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**
 just remove adjustpan it will work and also use scrolling in that page then on tapping the respective input field virtual keyboard popups and pushes the input field upwards and you can see what you gonna enter in your input field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Android API target lever of the project 13 or higher, not from the Android Manifest file.

In order to set your target:
      Right-click on the project -> Proprieties -> Android 
      then choose Android which have the "API level" 13 or higher.

if you are planning to use push notification in your application make sure that to choose the "Google APIs" with "API Level" 13 or higher

Comment: but i need android API Level 8 onwards

Comment: this is not phonegap issue, it's android issue

Comment: then how can i solve this one? i tried with normal html using webview with native app that text field working fine. but phonegap text field only its not visible..

Comment: <div  data-role="content">
<div class="lable">Name:<input type="text"></div>
<div class="lable">Text1:<input type="text"></div>  
<div class="lable">Text2:<input type="text"></div>  
<div class="lable">TextArea1:<textarea></textarea></div>
<div class="lable">TextArea2:<textarea> </textarea></div>
<div class="lable">TextArea3:<textarea></textarea></div> 
</div>