# Scroll to input field in the React Native WebView Android

Tags: android, webview, react-native

We are using React Native for mobile app development. We have WebView component where are some predefined input fields placed in the text of WebView html.

The problem is that when we select input field for edit - View is not scrolled to show actual input when keyboard appears.

We cant use

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

since we are using out custom navigation bar to control the application state.
The best description of this problem was found here:
[input field hidden when soft keyboard appears in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575999/input-field-hidden-when-soft-keyboard-appears-in-phonegap)

But none of the variants worked for us.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?