# When displaying the keyboard on Android, it hides my inputs

Tags: android, cordova, html-framework-7, dom7

I’m having a problem: displaying the keyboard on Android, it hides my inputs making it difficult to fill out the form.

Framework front end FrameWork7 working with Apache Cordova

[Descrição do problema.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrllz.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input field hidden when soft keyboard appears in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575999/input-field-hidden-when-soft-keyboard-appears-in-phonegap)

Comment: The problem is another.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should be fixed by adding one line in your AndroidManifest.xml file inside your desired activity tag. 
For example:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, it follows the error that was generated after adding the lines in my **AndroidManifest.XML**.


[Screen Problem](http://oi64.tinypic.com/2zegk02.jpg)

Comment: Can you give me more details about the code snippets you inserted above?

Comment: Okay, then try with this:

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: Here is the complete AndroidManifest.xml file https://pastebin.com/dK1QVfSD

Answer (score 0):

finally I resolved "partially" my problem, I made the update of my framework (framework7 version 1.4 for version 2.0) and poft! problem solved.

Download version 2.0
https://github.com/framework7io/framework7/releases/tag/v2.0.2